# git command output to a file

Tags: git, file, output

I am using Ubuntu OS and I tried to execute the git command as follows:

```
git clone -v https://senuser:xxxx@bitbucket.org/senxxxx/xxxxx.git > /home/ubuntu/output1.txt 2>&1.
```

But Output shows:

```
ubuntu@dev:~ [04:24:16]$ more output1.txt 
Cloning into 'xxxxxxx'...
POST git-upload-pack (252 bytes)
ubuntu@dev:~ [04:24:24]$
```

But if I execute the command manually I am getting follows:

```
ubuntu@-dev:~ [03:28:36]$ sh testgitpull.sh 
Cloning into 'xxxxxxaws'...
Password for 'https://senuser@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Counting objects: 56, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
ubuntu@xxxx-dev:~ [03:28:48]$
```

Can someone please help how to get the above kind of output instead of 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

why not the following command?

```
git clone -v https://senuser:xxxx@bitbucket.org/senxxxx/xxxxx.git &> /home/ubuntu/output1.txt
```

For details, please refer to [what-does-devnull-21-mean](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/)

Comment: Hi, When I ran like this I got below, but nothing inside my output. ubuntu$ sh testgitpull2.sh 
Cloning into 'rydetestaws'...
POST git-upload-pack (240 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 56, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
remote: Total 56 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
ubuntu@ryde-dev:~ [08:18:41]$ more output1.txt 
ubuntu@ryde-dev:~ [08:18:52]$. But I need the details inside the output1.txt file.